# Conda environment creation eats up a lot of space

Tags: anaconda, conda

I want to create a docker image, on Google VM.
One of the steps of the image is a conda environment creation. This is the command from the dockerfile (i am omiting the RUN):

```
conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml
```

This command installs a lot of packages and i end up without disk space.

I have two questions.

1. I am not sure what the `-f environment.yml` does. I search for this flag online, but i could not find any example together with a .yml file.
2. Can i remove some of the un-necessary packages before the installation happens?

Comment: 1) https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file

Comment: 2) How much disk space are the packages taking? Are you sure that they are unecessary?

Comment: Thank you. I am reading that doc. On second investigation, i am not entirely sure that the packages are not needing, and i do not think i will mess around with them.

Comment: Is the disk space used that significant?

Comment: Conda commands are documented: `conda env create --help`

Answer (score 1):

1. `-f` is an alias for `--file`
2. What constitutes an unnecessary package? (I assume you have nothing unnecessary in your environment file.) Maybe you're asking about the packages bundled by installing a complete Anaconda distribution? You may find [this](https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/03/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-cheatsheet.html) guide helpful (including some links in the intro).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at some of [Conda Forge's images](https://hub.docker.com/u/condaforge) to get an idea of best practice examples, maybe [Miniforge3 4.10.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/condaforge/miniforge3/4.10.1-0/images/sha256-22dfe1507e02261f1c20d7ddd470e8039b162cdf077351b7bb71f419205f465d?context=explore) to suggest a specific one.

At minimum one should make an effort to clean after every Conda operation, and do it in a chained operation so Docker doesn't save an intermediate with temporary files. A start would be

```
RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml && conda clean -afy
```