# Building a docker image on Google VM fails - on conda set up stage

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, dockerfile, conda

I am trying to build a docker image on a Google VM.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN conda install conda-build
RUN apt-get install -y git
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/cadquery/cadquery.git
WORKDIR /cadquery
RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate cq" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/cq/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /testing
RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install shortuuid
RUN pip install pytest
```

This builds successfully on my system, however, when run on Google VM, it get's stuck on the 8th line (`RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml`)

Take a look at the last lines of the terminal output. This is where it gets stuck:

```
readline-8.1         | 295 KB    | ########## | 100% 
fonts-conda-ecosyste | 4 KB      | ########## | 100% 
qt-5.12.9            | 99.5 MB   | ########## | 100% 
pytest-cov-2.12.0    | 21 KB     | ########## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/opt/conda/envs/cq/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Obtaining file:///cadquery (from -r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting sphinxcadquery
  Downloading sphinxcadquery-1.3.3.tar.gz (264 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinx in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-jsmath in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: babel>=1.3 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: imagesize in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-devhelp in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: snowballstemmer>=1.1 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.7.12)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.5.0 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.12 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments>=2.0 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (49.6.0.post20210108)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-qthelp in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-applehelp in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.3 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2015.7 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from babel>=1.3->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0.0rc2 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.3->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.0->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.0->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.0->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.0->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /opt/conda/envs/cq/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging->sphinx->sphinxcadquery->-r /cadquery/condaenv.3xeeoxvp.requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.4.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: sphinxcadquery
  Building wheel for sphinxcadquery (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for sphinxcadquery (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for sphinxcadquery: filename=sphinxcadquery-1.3.3-py3-none-any.whl size=267454 sha256=f8a56addcf66427e2f0490609f443adc7a8183b3ffecfa6b3ab65b7f31d11699
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/a6/6d/ee/07f300a53c94956b21d8defe8a489bc80d68b6b029a3e88019
Successfully built sphinxcadquery
Installing collected packages: sphinxcadquery, cadquery
  Running setup.py develop for cadquery
Successfully installed cadquery-2.1 sphinxcadquery-1.3.3

done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate cq
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

Comment: Do you have enough disk space to build your image ? Just saying that because I saw recently a similar issue on SO.

Comment: @norbjd Yes, i increased the disk size.

Comment: No matter the disk space, the problem remains.

Comment: Can you run your `Dockerfile` commands directly inside a container : `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh continuumio/miniconda3` and then `apt install`, `conda` commands, etc (in the order of the commands inside your `Dockerfile`) ?

Comment: I am confused.. I used this command `sudo docker build -t cq_image .`

Comment: I don't see any problem in what is shown here. Conda seems to finish without issue. Also, you haven't heeded (or responded to) the recommendation I provided in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538009/570918), that is, you should be chaining your commands into a single RUN and clean up your Conda (e.g., `RUN cmd1 && cmd2 && ... && conda clean -afy`).

Comment: @norbjd You mean i should use different standalone commands? I should modify the dockerfile? I am confused...

Comment: @merv No it's not ok because the prompt stops at the 8th step and the rest is never finished. The `pip install flask, shortuuid, pytest` never happen. Sorry for not responding, it must have been that i did not understand it. Here, i have only one conda command. So i am not sure what i should chain together. Should i do `RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml && conda clean -afy`? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @user1584421 yes at minimum. To clarify, I mean RUN commands (of which you have 9), not Conda commands. Every time you start a new RUN command Docker dumps an intermediate image, which leads to accumulated space. Unless you really expect to have additional images that branch off from one of those intermediates, they are unnecessary and could be contributing to your issue.

Comment: @merv Thank you but it still is not clear what you mean.... Should i nest the first group of three RUNs together, then one set on its own, then one group of twos nested together and then the last one? I want to thank you for taking the time to help me, but could you please create an answer with how the dockerfile should look? I have trouble understanding verbally... Sorry if its too much to ask....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason i don't know, the prompt stayed at that position i typed, for a long time.

I assumed the process was stuck, because this behavior did not happen on my system, just on Google VM.

However, if you wait long enough, everything works.